# ip forwarding enabled by kube-proxy

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, kube-proxy

I am trying to run kubernetes on a device. And the device have some security concerns. one of them is that i cannot enable packet forwarding on node (host machine).

I am run kubernetes 1.16.3 version with kube-proxy in IPVS mode. As soon as kube-proxy comes up the ipv4 forwarding is enabled.

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I want to disable this behavior. I am stuck in this and not able to find where i can change to disable ip_forward being set by kube-proxy.

Also,  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward being set 1 is it a security concern ?
Thanks

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do that? It would lock the node communication.

Comment: mine is a single node clusters.And for security reason i want to disable it